# Start a .NET executable for debugging in visual studio?

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to determine an internal invocation exception that's being raised by some assemblies when they're invoked by addinutil.exe. I need to know because I'm having difficulties installing SQL management studio 2008 where the "Visual Studio Tools for Applications" component fails due to this command that the MSI installer attempts to perform:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\addinutil.exe" -PipelineRoot:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTA\Pipeline\." -Rebuild -Silent
```

Then I get this:

```
Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

There have been suggested solutions to this by simply re-installing .NET 3.5/4.0, but re-installing 3.5 is difficult since it's part of Windows 7. I've done the "sfc.exe /scannow" command but this error still pops up.

I've taken the trin_aide.msi out of the SQL Express install to try different attempts at installing it. I've sent the installation to a friend and it worked perfectly. I've even attempted to perform the `addinutil.exe` command in the command prompt and it worked fine on his machine.

Now I want to know how to start a .NET executable in visual studio where I can view exceptions in the log window, if that works of course. I can't do "Attach to Process" because the command exits immediately.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a registry setting that allows you to [automatically attach a debugger every time an executable is started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed.aspx):

```
key = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\
    currentversion\image file execution option\YourApp.exe
string name = debugger
string value = vsjitdebugger.exe
```

One of the stated goals is to allow you to debug custom setup actions.

Comment: Oh neat, that's useful for when I don't feel like loading VS! Thanks anyways, I forgot to update my question. I found out if I went to my project's settings in Visual Studio, I can start any executable I want instead of the project's build, then if I go under the "debug" and go to "exceptions", I can check what kind of exceptions I want to break on. I found out there was some bug where `System.AddInStore::Rebuild` wasn't able to load the two assemblies it needed. More info here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/2e0dd7cd-bfa3-412c-95a4-8f7ee81c80a1